# Dealing with undefined attributes in controlled fields in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

So I'm just starting to learn Reactjs and I'm building a simple application to manage a simple list with objects.

All objects have some common attributes 'a, b, c' but some have 'd' and some have 'e, and some have both, as follows:

```
this.state.list = [
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3
    },
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3,
        d: 4,
        e: 5
    },
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3,
        d: 4
    },
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3,
        e: 5
    },
]
```

I have inputs bound to each different attribute, which will dinamically change according to the selected item:

```
<input value={this.state.list[selectedIndex].a} />
<input value={this.state.list[selectedIndex].b} />
<input value={this.state.list[selectedIndex].c} />
<input value={this.state.list[selectedIndex].d} />
<input value={this.state.list[selectedIndex].e} />
```

The problem is, when I change the selected item, the inputs don't take into account the missing attributes (because they are undefined).

I could simply use a conditional to check for undefined attributes and not print the input, but I want to be able to add 'd' and 'e' to objects whenever the respective input is filled on objects that don't have them.

What is the best way to deal with this? Is it feasible or should I just standardize all objects to have all attributes, even if they are empty? Is there a "right" way to get this done (which won't cause me trouble in the future)?

Comment: Have you tried `<input value={this.state.list[selectedIndex].d || ''} />`?

Comment: during addition of input value add the empty inputs too. this would remove the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
(selectedIndex) => {
  const {
    a='',
    b='',
    c='',
    d='',
    e=''
  } = this.state.list[selectedIndex];

  return (
    <input value={a} />
    <input value={b} />
    <input value={c} />
    <input value={d} />
    <input value={e} />
  )
}
```

This is called [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) with default values.

Comment: thank you for introducing me to the destructuring concept, it looks like it could come in handy in other situations aswell

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put something like this in your render function:

```
  {
    Object.keys(this.state.list[selectedIndex]).map(input=>(
      <input value={this.state.list[selectedIndex][input]} />
    ))
  }
```

Comment: this seems like it would work, but if I need different input types it would generate a lot more verbose, so I picked cameron's answer instead